# Как ограничить использование памяти в Apache и mod_fcgi?

Tags: linux, apache, centos, производительность

Доброго дня!

Есть сервер со множеством сайтов
8 cores, RAM 50 GB, Centos 6.5, Apache 2.2+PHP 5.3.3 (cgi-fcgi)
В последнее время процессы php-cgi отжирают всю память, как следствие, сервер валится в OOM  и OOM killer начинает килять все подряд. Посчитал по формуле сколько нужно Maxclients для апача и уменьшил FcgidMaxProcesses но не помогло, через 2-3 дня вся память сожрана и начинается свопиться.

Как можно ограничить использование памяти для php-cgi модуля?

Apache

```
IfModule prefork.c>
        StartServers            3
        MinSpareServers         5
        MaxSpareServers         10
        ServerLimit             24
        MaxClients              150
        MaxRequestsPerChild     5000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
        StartServers             5
        MinSpareThreads          15
        MaxSpareThreads          100
        ServerLimit              24
        MaxClients               150
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestsPerChild      10000
</IfModule>
```

mod_fcgi.conf

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidBusyScanInterval         120
FcgidBusyTimeout              300
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass     300
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass     1
FcgidErrorScanInterval        3
FcgidIdleScanInterval         60
FcgidIdleTimeout              120
FcgidIOTimeout                120
FcgidConnectTimeout           3
FcgidMaxProcesses             1000
FcgidMaxRequestInMem          65536
FcgidMaxRequestLen            1073741824
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess    5000
# ^ Sollte mit PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS uebereinstimmen in /var/fcgi-bin.d/x/wrapper-php-x.x.x
FcgidOutputBufferSize         65536
FcgidFixPathinfo              1
#FcgidProcessLifeTime          1200
FcgidProcessLifeTime         600
FcgidProcessTableFile         /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
FcgidIPCDir                   /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgidsock
FcgidSpawnScore               1
FcgidSpawnScoreUpLimit        10
FcgidTerminationScore         2
FcgidTimeScore                1
FcgidZombieScanInterval       3
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону cgroups. Этот механизм ядра как раз позволяет ограничить ресурсы(процессор, сеть, память, жесткий диск) для определенных процессов.
На [сайте Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ru-RU/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html) хорошо всё задокументировано и на русском.